# html5 media attribute question

Tags: html

I was wondering why shouldn't Authors use pixel units with the "tty" media type value for the media attribute? What type should they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because pixels don't make sens on `tty` devices. Think good old terminals (or old fashioned mechanical typewriters). They don't have pixels, they pretty much only have (whole) characters in their display capabilities.

Comment: can you give me an example using the tty value and media attribute if you can?